# Word That describes a Story that Undermines Tropes

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for a single word used to describe the process in Storytelling where a story undermines the concept of a genre/trope/or previous work by doing things backwards from this. Not a parody, exactly, but the same sort of thing in a non-humorous manner.

I am 99% sure I know this word exists.

Comment: Every ques­tion should de­scribe the asker’s prior ef­forts to find an an­swer, and ex­plain why the re­sults were not ad­e­quate to an­swer the ques­tion. Some re­search is re­quired on ev­ery ques­tion. This is called our re­search re­quire­ment. Re­search can take many forms: check­ing ref­er­ences such as an on­line English dic­tio­nary, the­saurus, or gram­mar, search­ing this site for sim­i­lar ques­tions, search­ing the web, or putting sub­stan­tial thought into the ques­tion on your own. Please **[ᴇᴅɪᴛ]** your ques­tion and de­tail your re­search re­sults.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One term you might apply is *deconstruction*, in the sense that it dismantles the conventional expectations of the trope or genre. This usage, as defined by [TVTropes](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/Deconstruction), has a more generic sense than the practice of [deconstruction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deconstruction) described by Jacques Derrida. Be wary of readers confusing the two if you're writing for an academic audience.

Another term you might mean is *subversion*, as in subverting an expectation. Subversion is pretty close in meaning to undermining: to quote [this answer](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/29855/what-does-it-mean-to-subvert-a-trope),

> To subvert [a trope] is to make deliberate use of it, but with a change that undercuts or reverses the typical meaning.

For example, writing an adventure story where a princess sets out to slay a dragon (like the children's book *[The Paper Bag Princess](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Paper_Bag_Princess)*) subverts the expectation that a prince would set out to rescue a princess. It isn't parody, but rather a story that takes a different path by subverting genre conventions and audience expectations.